# Para ver cuando entrara/cuándo entró Claudia

Tags: gramática

Quisiera confirmar si es "cuando entrara" o cuándo entró" en "`[Me senté de cara a la puerta, para ver cuando entrara Claudia.][1]`" y por qué - es que creo que es "cuándo entró" en vez de "cuando entrara".¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Para ver"(con el fin de ver) indica que es el futuro inmediato de esa primera acción en el pasado del hablante, entonces si dice "para ver cuando <s>entró</s>" suena incongruente porque es algo que se está desarrollando sucesivamente. Diría:

> Me **senté** de cara a la puerta para verla **entrar**.(+Infinitivo)

o

> Me **iba a sentar** de cara a la puerta para ver(la) cuando **entrara**(subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto)

o

> Me **habría sentado** de cara a la puerta para ver **si hubiera** entrado.

Con el subjuntivo no deja claro el hablante si Claudia entró o no, con iba indica que es algo que no se concretó. Si dice "para ver si entraba"(si se decidía a hacerlo) debería decir "me sentaba" porque sugiere que es algo o bien repetitivo o que son acciones que se desarrollan simultáneamente).

> Me **sentaba** de cara a la puerta para ver si **entraba**.

Si se quiere decir que a veces entraba, se usa la coma(,) o para hacer una pausa:

> Me sentaba de cara a la puerta, para verla, cuando entraba(hace enfásis en que no siempre entraba, a veces)

Aclarar que "entrara" es "subjuntivo pretérito imperfecto" y no "futuro simple(entrar**á**)".

También se podría decir:

> Me senté aquí para ver(la) cuando **entre**(suena más coloquial)

El problema es que al decir "entre", que es "subjuntivo presente", indica que está pendiente o a la espera de un evento futuro pero en el presente, no en el pasado del hablante.

EDIT: Con tilde cambia todo, diría:

> Me senté de cara a la puerta para ver a qué hora llegó.

> Me senté de cara a la puerta para ver, cuáaaando  llegó.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones!

Answer (score 0):

En la oración en cuestión:

(1) Me senté de cara a la puerta(,) para ver cuando **entrara** Claudia.

lo correcto es el pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo "entrara", pues se refiere a una acción futura posible, pero no segura. "Entró" es incorrecto ya que solo apunta al pasado, por ejemplo:

(2) Me senté de cara a la puerta cuando **entró** Claudia.

Otra oración posible similar a (1) es:

(3) Me senté de cara a la puerta(,) para ver cuándo **entraría** Claudia.

Nótese que, a diferencia de (1), en (3) es un hecho que Claudia entraría en algún momento. Nótese asimismo que en (1) "cuando" es una conjunción y no lleva tilde, mientras que en (3) "cuándo" es un adverbio interrogativo y lleva tilde. La razón de esta alternancia coincide con la alternancia de los tiempos verbales: "para ver cuando entrara Claudia" solo indica probabilidad (para ver el momento en que entrara, si es que entraba), mientras que "para ver cuándo entraría Claudia" indica certeza (para ver en qué momento entraría).